# Trying to copy every nth file from subfolders of a folder in same folder structure to a folder

Tags: powershell

this only copies the empty folders. i am trying to copy every nth file from subfolders of a folder in same folder structure to a folder

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem "D:\n.a.d\excel backups\autorecover backups\Excel\New folder (2)"
$i = 0
Do{
    $files[$i]|copy-Item -Dest "D:\n.a.d\excel backups\autorecover backups\Excel\New folder (3)"
    $i=$i+2
}While($i -le $files.count)
}
```

Comment: You code works fine for me, it copies every nth file from "New folder (2)" to "New Folder (3)".

The problem you're having should be evident by taking a look at the content of $Files though, if you just output that instead of doing the other stuff, what are you seeing?

Comment: it is copying but not from the subfolders , only the root folder

Comment: Ah ok! Do you want all files in all subfolders copied directly to "New Folder (3)" or do you need the folderstructure intact as well?

Comment: with folderstructure intact

Comment: i copied that code from somewhere , tweaked it a little but couldn't make it work fully

Answer (score 1):

All right, here's one way to do it! There may be a cleaner way but this one works and gets the folder structure right in the destination.

```
# Add our paths to variables
$SourceFolder = 'D:\n.a.d\excel backups\autorecover backups\Excel\New folder (2)'
$Destination = 'D:\n.a.d\excel backups\autorecover backups\Excel\New folder (3)'

# Variable for n, where n is the gap between files you want copied
$n = 2

# Get all subfolders
$AllSubFolders = Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Recurse -Directory

# Add our source root folder to the folder list
$AllFolders = $AllSubFolders.FullName + $SourceFolder

# Loop over all folders, figure out the correct destination folder path by joining the destination +
# the current folder with the $SourceFolder part removed (that's the .SubString-part) and create matching
# folders in the destination, then get all files in the folder and copy every nth file in a similar manner
# as your question.
foreach ($Folder in $AllFolders) {
    $CurrentDestFolder = (Join-Path $Destination ($Folder.Substring($SourceFolder.Length)))
    [void](New-Item -Path $CurrentDestFolder -Force -ItemType Directory)
    $CurrentFiles = Get-ChildItem $Folder -File
    $i = 0
    while ($i -lt $CurrentFiles.Count) {
        $CurrentFiles[$i] | Copy-Item -Destination (Join-Path $CurrentDestFolder $_)
        $i = $i+$n
    }
}
```